# how to convert string values to numbers in a mixed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a mixed array of values all string values. I want to take the string values representing a number and convert them to ints. Here is my array:

```
const data = 'new york;10.99;2000';

I split it transforming it:

const transData = data.split(';');

transData = ["new york", "10.99", "2000"]
```

I would like to iterate over that and return two clean int's with a string value for all non number strings. I am a bit stumped. I know this is easy to some but I have tried forEach, for, map, and I still get a NaN value for the first array member. I can't seem to filter or skip it even with an "if" check using for instance:

```
  for(let i=0; i < transData.length; i++)
    if(transData[i] != NaN){
     transData[i] = + transData[i];
    }else{continue};
```

I know how this works transData[i] = + transData[i]; 
I just can't seem to automate this thing with iteration/filter/map/whatever..

Any help greatly appreciated. These are baby steps into big boy/girl thinking in javascript.

Here are some of the methods I have tried:

```
const data = 'new york;10.99;2000';
const transData = data.split(';');

// transData[1] = + transData[1];
// transData[2] = + transData[2];
console.log(transData);



const filteredTransData = transData.filter(data => data > 0);
filteredTransData.forEach((data, idx) => {
filteredTransData[idx] = + filteredTransData[idx];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN === NaN` will always return `false`. To check if element is `NaN` you need to use `isNaN` function.

```js
const transData = ["new york", "10.99", "2000"];
for(let i = 0; i< transData.length; i++){
  if(!isNaN(transData[i])){
    transData[i] = +transData[i];
  }
}
console.log(transData)
```

Whenever you need to get a new value for each element of array based on previous value its better to use `map()`

```js
const transData = ["new york", "10.99", "2000"];
const res = transData.map(x => isNaN(x) ? x : +x);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: That is how my mind wants to see the solution, using a loop. Thanks Maheer!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `||` operater with `.map()` to get the desired output. As `NaN` is a falsey value so it would return the string under consideration as it is if it can't be converted to a number by `Number`:

```js
const data = 'new york;10.99;2000';

const result = data.split(";").map(s => Number(s) || s);

console.log(result);
```

As pointed by @Maheer Ali:

> Above solution has a limitation. It won't convert String `"0"` to Number `0` as 0 is a falsey value.

So we may use some other solution posted or we may explicitly apply a check for zero (0) where this modified array is being used.

Comment: Brilliant. I new it had to be way easier than I was making it. Thanks so much Mohammad!

Comment: @Bradley This will not convert `'0'` to number. Because `Number('0')` will return `0` and its a falsy value

Comment: Maheer you are correct sir. It appeared to work for me as I did not have a 0. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using MAP function

```
data.split(';').map((x)=>{
 x= !isNaN(x)? parseFloat(x):x; 
 return x;
})
```

Comment: I like this one. I am learning a lot about map here. Thanks Jaydip!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Maheer Ali's method is good. I just modified all code)

```js
const data = 'new york;10.99;2000;0;-1;-2.45';

let transData = Array
    .from(data.split(';'), x => parseFloat(x))
    .filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) );

console.log(transData);
```

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) - creates a number array from the string array.

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - removes NaN from the number array

Comment: Nice.  Clearly explained. "Array.from() - creates a number array from the string array.

Array.filter() - removes NaN from the number array"